# Oracle SQL*Loader with skip_index_maintenance

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds, sql-loader

We'd like to upload over one hundred million data into Oracle RDS, as fast as possible.
So far, we verified following SQL*Loader options are the fastest way.

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT=TRUE,skip_index_maintenance=TRUE)
UNRECOVERABLE
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'C:\temp\huge_data.csv'
REPLACE
INTO TABLE "TEST"."HUGE_DATA_TBL"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
```

Thanks to skip_index_maintenance option, we can upload data faster, without any index maintenance and the index would be unusable status after loading.
But we actually need the index after uploading data as next step for extraction.

I'm just wondering any other faster way to load, or is there any options after skip index maintenance but rebuild index automatically at the end of loading, without altering index rebuild manually.
For example, REENABLE option can work, not only constraints but also for index?

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If there is one particular index that you need to be ready once the load is finished, you could sort the CSV data in order of those index columns, and then load the data with the SORTED INDEXES clause.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-571EC032-0C25-483A-BC0D-2C27A7B64D64.htm#SUTIL1316

Other indexes will still need to be rebuilt, but you should have one index to work with.

Comment: Many thanks for your useful information, Connor. It's worth to try for us. Thank you so much and have a wonderful evening :)